# Limit WordPress post navigation to custom post type and current tag

Tags: php, wordpress, filter, navigation

I'm trying to show prev and next nav links to navigate between posts in a custom post type AND only within a custom tag of the current post.

Post type is 'lessons'
Tag taxonomy is 'course_tag'

There are only 2 tags: tag 1 and tag 2

If viewing a lesson with tag 1, post nav should display the previous and next posts with tag 1
If viewing a lesson with tag 2, post nav should display the previous and next posts with tag 2

I don't want this to affect any post type other than lessons.

```
add_filter('my_post_navigation_args', function( $args ){
   $args=array(
    'post_type' => lessons,
    'tax_query' => array(
      array(
      'taxonomy' => 'course_tag',
      'field' => 'slug',
      'terms' => $term->slug
      )
    ));
    return $args;
});
```

This isn't showing any errors but it's not working.
Thank you.

Comment: What hook/filter is `my_post_navigation_args` supposed to be?

Comment: Ah, maybe that's the issue? It's theme specific. `kadence_post_navigation_args`

This works for categories in posts post type, but that's not what I'm after:

`add_filter('kadence_post_navigation_args', function( $args ){
   $args['in_same_term'] = true;
    return $args; 
});`